# Двоеточие в БСП

Tags: пунктуация

Хочу разобраться. Допустим ли первый вариант - двоеточие после "сказать" без кавычек? Второй вариант сомнений не вызывает.

Подводя краткие итоги, можно твердо сказать: на сегодняшний день мы видим, что выбранные и внедряемые нами современные решения по автоматизации конструкторской деятельности дают ощутимые результаты, и сомнений в целесообразности проводимой  работы нет.

Или:

Подводя краткие итоги, можно твердо сказать, что на сегодняшний день мы видим:  выбранные и внедряемые нами современные решения по автоматизации конструкторской деятельности дают ощутимые результаты, и сомнений в целесообразности проводимой  работы нет.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:  Подводя краткие итоги, можно твердо сказать: на сегодняшний день мы видим, что выбранные и внедряемые нами современные решения по автоматизации конструкторской деятельности дают ощутимые результаты и сомнений в целесообразности проводимой работы нет.

Это БСП со значением изъяснения, кавычки не нужны. Второй вариант применять не стоит: "можно твердо сказать, что на сегодняшний день мы видим" звучит не лучшим образом.

Comment: Но у Розенталя есть пункт о введении описания или изложения каких-либо фактов посредством глаголов "видеть", "смотреть", "слышать", "понимать" и т.п. Или это относится только к художественной речи? Потому что мне больше нравится второй вариант - он мне кажется менее избитым.

Comment: Разумеется, в БСП могут использоваться глаголы со значением восприятия (вижу, слышу). Мне просто сочетание кажется странным: можно сказать, что видим. Во втором же варианте эти выражения расположены в разных частях БСП.

Comment: Здесь возможно два варианта.Все зависит от того ,что именно вам нужно подчеркнуть. То что можно увидеть или то, что твердо можно сказать. Но я согласен с Софией. Первый вариант все же предпочтителен. Т.к. речь идет именно о том, что именно с уверенностью можно сказать. Что касается Розенталя: не могли бы вы указать страницу на правило?

Comment: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm

Comment: И, кстати, об отсутствии запятой перед "и". София, вы хотите сказать, что здесь общее придаточное предложение "на сегодняшний день мы видим"?

Comment: Здесь однородные придаточные: мы видим, что (1) и (2).